# Mysql Prevent insert with insert trigger condition not met

Tags: mysql

I am trying to setup a trigger so an insert does not occur if a condition is not met.

I thought the below was the way to do it but i am not sure

I am getting an error 
/* SQL Error (1407): Bad SQLSTATE: '45000 ' */

Can anyone let me know why I am getting this error and the best way for me to prevent an insert if the condition is not met in mysql.

```
DELIMITER $$
SHOW WARNINGS$$
USE `warrington_central`$$ 

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_image_comment_section_check
BEFORE INSERT ON image_comment FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

 DECLARE error_msg varchar(255);
IF New.section != (SELECT id from section where section = "image")
    THEN SET    error_msg = "Cannot insert a comment into this section as it is the wrong section type";
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000 'SET MESSAGE_TEXT = error_msg;


END IF;

END
$$

SHOW WARNINGS$$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLSTATE is required to be a a 5 character string unless previously declared using [DECLARE ... CONDITION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-condition.html);

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000 'SET MESSAGE_TEXT = error_msg;
```

You're trying to set SQLSTATE to '45000 ' (note the space) which is 6 characters long. Fix the spacing and you should not see the message again (it is also reflected in your error message, but the space is a bit hard to see)

Comment: thanks what does SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = error_msg; actually do- will this prevent the insert- just read about it online what does 45000 mean

Comment: @MatthewChambers SIGNAL is the way to “return” an error from a trigger, and the '45000' means "Unhandled user-defined exception." which is the error code. The MESSAGE_TEXT is an optional clear text version of the error message. Yes, it should stop the insert from happening.